# Compute $\int_{t-2T}^T t-\tau\cdot 1 \;d\tau = [t\tau - \frac{\tau^2}{2}]_{t-2T}^{T}$

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-verification, indefinite-integrals

Compute $\displaystyle\int\limits_{t-2T}^T t-\tau\cdot 1 \;d\tau$

\begin{align}
\displaystyle&\int\limits_{t-2T}^T t-\tau\cdot 1 \;d\tau \\
&=\left[t\tau - \frac{\tau^2}{2}\right]_{t-2T}^{T}\\
&=tT-\frac{T^2}{2}-t(t-2T)-\frac12(t-2T)^2\\
&=tT-\frac{T^2}{2}-t^2+2tT-\frac 12(t^2-4tT+4T^2)\\
&=tT-\frac{T^2}{2}-t^2+2tT-\frac 1 2t^2+2Tt-2T^2\\
&=\frac{-3T^2}{2}+5tT-\frac{5tT^2}{2}
\end{align}

Is this correct?

Comment: I got this here $$1/2\, \left( T+t \right)  \left( 3\,T-t \right) $$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner can you share your process to the solution?

Comment: In evaluating the antiderivative you made a plus-minus mistake. It should be $+(t-2T)^2/2$ instead of what you have.

Comment: Who uses $t$, $\tau$, and $T$ in the same expression? Yikes

Comment: @MatthewLeingang The taskt is from a lecture. I don't know why.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not blaming you.

Comment: It's fine, I know you don't. Someone thought it's a good idea, but it's rather confusing, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$[t\tau-\tau^2/2]_{t-2T}^{T}=tT-\frac{T^2}{2}-\left(t(t-2T)-\frac{(t-2T)^2}{2}\right)$$
and this is
$$tT-\frac{T^2}{2}-t^2+2tT+\frac{1}{2}t^2-2tT+2T^2$$

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that mistake.